# add_post_meta() is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hope you people are doing good today. :)

i used **add_post_meta()** and **update_post_meta()** in function but neither add_post_meta() function working nor update_post_meta.

Here is code.

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
add_post_meta($post_id, 'counter_meta', 'Dani');
$return = get_post_meta($post_id, 'counter_meta', true );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($return);
exit;
```

it's return nothing :(

I checked before id is coming in `post_id` variable.

Any help.?

Comment: It is pretty debugable code. You should debug it before asking such question.

Comment: What do you mean Milap ?

Comment: Did you get `post_id` in `$post_id` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$post_id = $post->ID;
add_post_meta($post_id, 'counter_meta', 'Dani');
$return = get_post_meta($post_id, 'counter_meta', true );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($return);
exit;
```

Comment: Hi Bilal Thanks for reply. But i can,t use  $post_id = $post->ID; because i am not getting the post ID from loop.I,m getting through Ajax Call so i must need to get the post ID like this $post_id = $_POST['post_id']; Post ID is coming fine its not the problem with ID.

Comment: Hi Danish, I have tried your code by ajax call and it worked fine. Try to find out bug in your own code.

Comment: What is the problem with this code .? :( Can you tell.